# Mavericks -- Enable menu ("File", "Edit", "View", etc) bar on non-primary multi screen monitor for selected applications

Tags: multiple-monitors, osx-mavericks

I'm not sure if this is possible yet, but seeing that Apple appears to be slowly solving its multi-display glitches, for example with its Mavericks fix of the full-screen problem blocking out all other displays...

I have three separate displays running right now through two thunderbolt ports on a new 2013 model macbook pro. Its pretty awesome, but, I always have to move my cursor to the primary (normally, the laptop) screen to be able to access the top menu bar (just clarifying)

[image: Just to clarify. That.]

Wanting to be able to view the menu bar on all of my monitors, not just the primary (laptop) one.

Comment: Just to make certain: You're saying that the menu bar (with the "Google Earth Pro" example in your screenshot) is *only* shown on your primary display in 10.9 (Mavericks) and not on the other displays?

Comment: Yes ------------

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change which monitor is the primary one, in the simplest case for example by closing your laptop while a second display is active (turns laptop-designated display into primary display, thus gaining the Menu bar), but I haven't figured out how to make the bar show up on alternate screens. Why, for example with Google Earth when wanting to save My Places

Comment: You're right. I just had to make sure I understood (There's another similar thing you could've wanted). BTW: to change the primary display, go to **SysPrefs** > **Displays** > **Arrangement** and drag the menu bar to the display you want to make primary (Not that you need it in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To get the menu bar to show up on all monitors, you'll need to enable **Displays have separate spaces**:

1. Go to **System Preferences...**
2. Click on **Mission Control**
3. Check **Displays have separate spaces**
4. Log out and log in again

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Olli The Apple logo doesn't show up in quite a few browsers, and becomes an ugly box/question mark.